# Tangent to a circle through a point

Tags: mathematics, angles

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the following angle:

I know center (**p1**) and radius (**r**) of a circle. Given a point **p3** I want to calculate the angle **a** such as the tangent (**tan**) of the circle at point **p4**, points in **p3** direction.

Here's a figure:

[image]

Doesn anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `b` be the angle between vectors `p1p2` and `p1p3`. Its value can be computed as:

```
b = pi - atan2(p1p3.y, p1p3.x)
```

The angle between `p1p4` and `p1p3` is `b-a`. Since `p1p3p4` is a right-angled triangle, we know that `cos(b-a)` is the distance `p1p4` divided by the distance `p1p3`.

The answer is then:

```
a = pi - atan2(p1p3.y, p1p3.x) - acos(r / length(p1p3))
```

Replacing the second `-` with `+` will give you the second possible solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I google a lot searching answer to this, but I didn't find anything. Simple and clear solution!!

Answer (score -1):

I was going to calculate this, then I failed, then I googled, then I found people who failed multiple times as well. But in the end some seem to have gotten it right :).

Read [this entire thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/499818-tangents-to-a-circle-through-a-point/), it should lead you to the correct algorithm.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Doesn't the link have the exact answer? Btw the search query was "tangent circle point".

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Hah didn't know that. You are absolutely right, I even agree after reading that topic. Well I guess I never did this before :P.

Comment: Note that the thread in question seems to indicate that there are four possible answers. There must be something wrong there.

Comment: No there are 2 possible lines, but four possible vectors describing that line, hence the four solutions.